# Overriding ExecuteAsync on AuthenticateAttribute using Servicestack OrmLite

Tags: authentication, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We have a .net 6.0 MVC web application running with ServiceStack Ormlite 6.0.2.

We have a custom `AuthenticateAttribute` that extends the Servicestack AuthenticateAttribute. The intention is to to use this to query a secondary set of permissions that are stored against a `CustomAuthUserSession`, as we have split permissions (there are too many, and they can't all be stored in the JWT token cookie):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomRequiredPermissionAttribute : AuthenticateAttribute
{
    public List<string> RequiredPermissions { get; set; }

    public CustomRequiredPermissionAttribute(ApplyTo applyTo, params string[] permissions)
    {
        this.RequiredPermissions = permissions.ToList();
        this.ApplyTo = applyTo;
        this.Priority = (int)RequestFilterPriority.RequiredPermission;
        this.HtmlRedirect = "~/PermissionDenied";
    }

    public CustomRequiredPermissionAttribute(params string[] permissions)
        : this(ApplyTo.All, permissions)
    { }

    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        //Do things here
    }
...
```

Essentially we want to use the `ExecuteAsync` function to check permissions against a second list, but overriding as above doesn't work. Debugging shows that the constructor is executed, but the `ExecuteAsync` method never is.

Changing the class above so that it extends from the `RequiredPermissionAttribute` with `public class CustomRequiredPermissionAttribute : RequiredPermissionAttribute` will result in the `RequiredPermissionAttribute` working as expected against the Servicestack Permissions list - but again, using an override on `ExecuteAsync` doesn't appear to work, it runs as if there are no changes to the `RequiredPermissionAttribute`.

Do our attributes need to be registered somewhere to get them to work, or are we attempting to use the wrong method with `ExecuteAsync`?

---

The attribute is used against the MVC controllers like this:

```
[Authenticate, CustomRequiredPermission(PermissionType.Read, PermissionEntity.Location)]
public class MyController : _BaseController
{
...
}
```

I tried removing the `Authenticate` attribute in case that was interfering, but the result was the same - the constructor for `CustomRequiredPermission` is hit but not `ExecuteAsync'. I also tried decorating a method instead of the class, but saw the same result again.

The reason we haven't overridden the `HasAnyPermissionsAsync` method is that we want to use the built-in servicestack permissions in most areas, but in the admin area we also check against the extended (admin) permissions. This way in most cases we don't need that extra database query to get the permissions and can just use the jwt permissions each time. If all else fails this may be a good back-up.

Ultimately it sounds like there's no registration process or something similar that we're missing, and it may be a case of trying to replicate the issue in a separate solution.

Answer (score 1):

These are all [Request Filter Attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) which should be decorated on your Service class or its methods, e.g:

```cs
[CustomRequiredPermission("permission1","permission2")]
public class MyService : Service
{
}
```

In which `ExecuteAsync` would be called, which is how all other built-in Request Filter attributes work.

It's not clear what else you're doing with the attribute for `ExecuteAsync` not to be called.

Instead of creating a custom Attribute you can try using a custom session with a  custom `HasAnyPermissionsAsync` implementation:

```cs
public class CustomUserSession
    : AuthUserSession
{
    public override Task<bool> HasAnyPermissionsAsync(
        ICollection<string> permissions, 
        IAuthRepositoryAsync authRepo, 
        IRequest req, 
        CancellationToken token=default)
    {
        //check custom list or
        return base.HasAnyPermissionsAsync(permissions, authRepo, req, token);
    }
}
```

That way you can continue to use the built-in `[RequiredPermission]` and `[RequiresAnyPermission]` attributes

Comment: Thanks for getting back so soon, I've updated the question to show usage. Even copying the code of a built-in attribute like the `RequiredPermissionAttribute` didn't hit any breakpoints in the ExecuteAsync, which is why I thought that maybe it had to be registered somewhere.

Comment: RequestFilter Attributes are only supported to run on ServiceStack Services, they wont work on Controller which are only hardcoded to look for builtin Auth Attributes using a [ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.cs). You could create your own MVC `ActionFilterAttribute` to implement any custom authorization logic.